# Cant get My adventure game to work correctly (choices do not work)

Tags: python

i am currently creating an zombie adventure game or a project using python, i have written it all out however some choices dont work, ive tried using else statements and elif statements and still cant get it to work correctly, can anyone see what the issue is?

this is the code:

```
print("Welcome to the zombie apocalypse game, Your name is Dion")
print("the apocalypse has been going on for the past year and a half")
print("you have been separated from your group and must make your way to the air field by making the right choices")
print("make the wrong choices and you will loose the game and die.")
print("some choices may seem correct at the time but will lead you down a path of death")
print("Lets Hope You Can Make It!")





answer = input ("Would you like to play the game? (yes/no)")

if answer.lower().strip() == "yes":

    answer = input("you are walking down a street, you reach a crossroad, would you like to go left or right? (left/right)").lower().strip()

if answer == "left":
        answer = input("you walking into a mugger, Do you fight or run? (fight/run)")

        if answer == "fight":
            print("Poor choice you were stabbed, YOU LOSE!!")

elif answer == "run":

        answer = input("nice choice, you ran away from the mugger, you now come to another split in the road, are you going left or right?? (left/right)")

        if answer == "left":
            print("you run into a large group of zombies,You have nothing to fight them off with and they eat you. You Loose")

elif answer == "right":

        answer = input("In the distance you see a fire and some tents, you can either go to the tents and see what happens or try to find your own shelter (tents/yourself)")

        if answer == "tents":
            print("You make your way upto the tents, stepping on a booby trap left the zombies, a spike goes through your foot and your scream attracts a heard of zombies and they kill you and all of the poeple in the tents")


else:

        answer = input("you find a small bulding that is empty, you decide to make camp here for the night, in the back you notice a generator, do you try and start it or leave it and sleep in the cold and dark? (start/leave)")

        if answer == "start":
            print("you have no idea what youre doing and pull the wrong leaver causing the generator to explode, killing you in the process. You loose")

        else:
            print("you stay in the cold and dark, during the night a small group of zombies made their way into the builiding with you as you didnt check for open doors or other entry points and they attack you in your sleep, you have now become a zombie. You Lose the game")




elif answer == "right":

        answer = input("you contiue down the path for a while longer, You come across a dead man, all beaten and with bite marks, you see that he has a gun, Do you take it or leave it? (take/leave)")

        if answer == "take":

            print("Stupid choice that was a zombie and now you have been bitten and now youre dead")

elif answer == "leave":

        answer = input("You continue down the path and see a large swarm of zombies you can either fight them or try and go through a building to escape them (fight/building")

        if answer == "fight":
            print("Pretty Stupid choice, theyre zombies and youre ... well youre you, and youre dead")


elif answer == "building":

        answer = input("okay were in the building, theres a zipwire on the roof or you can look for supplies? (zipewire/supplies)")

        if answer == "zipewire":
            print("you ran into a group of mainiacs and they have captured you and made you a slave, you lose!!")


elif answer == "supplies":

        answer = input("nice, you found food, clothes, a gun and keys to a car, are you going yo risk unlocking the car and making noise which could alert the zombies or are you going to find another way? (unlock/other)")

        if answer == "other":
            print("Poor choice there is to many of them and now youre dead")

elif answer == "unlock":

        answer = input("okay you got to the car and it has a full tank of fuel, its only a few hour drive to the air feild, do you drive there now in the dark or wait till the morning? (morning/now)")

        if answer == "morning":
            print("nope, the zombies are surrounding you and destory the car and you inside it, you lost")


elif answer == "now":
            print("you made it to the air strip and meet up with your friends, youre safe and you win the game!!!!")



else:
     print ("fine dont play :(")
```

if you choose left as the first option and then to run the game just stops when it should give more options and choices to progress in the game but it just doesnt happen and i dont know why. please can someone help.

Comment: What is not working? Also try playing around with the indents to ensure if they are right

Comment: Your code is a jumbled mess of `if-else`, I corrected the indents and posted an answer below which should work @the-real-fawcett

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future, I would suggest breaking down your code into smaller functions, then chaining all these `if-else` together such deep. I corrected the indents and it should work now

```py
print("Welcome to the zombie apocalypse game, Your name is Dion")
print("the apocalypse has been going on for the past year and a half")
print("you have been separated from your group and must make your way to the air field by making the right choices")
print("make the wrong choices and you will loose the game and die.")
print("some choices may seem correct at the time but will lead you down a path of death")
print("Lets Hope You Can Make It!")

answer = input ("Would you like to play the game? (yes/no)")

if answer.lower().strip() == "yes":

    answer = input("you are walking down a street, you reach a crossroad, would you like to go left or right? (left/right)").lower().strip()

    if answer == "left":
        answer = input("you walking into a mugger, Do you fight or run? (fight/run)")

        if answer == "fight":
            print("Poor choice you were stabbed, YOU LOSE!!")

        elif answer == "run":

            answer = input("nice choice, you ran away from the mugger, you now come to another split in the road, are you going left or right?? (left/right)")

            if answer == "left":
                print("you run into a large group of zombies,You have nothing to fight them off with and they eat you. You Loose")

            elif answer == "right":

                answer = input("In the distance you see a fire and some tents, you can either go to the tents and see what happens or try to find your own shelter (tents/yourself)")

                if answer == "tents":
                    print("You make your way upto the tents, stepping on a booby trap left the zombies, a spike goes through your foot and your scream attracts a heard of zombies and they kill you and all of the poeple in the tents")

                else:

                    answer = input("you find a small bulding that is empty, you decide to make camp here for the night, in the back you notice a generator, do you try and start it or leave it and sleep in the cold and dark? (start/leave)")

                    if answer == "start":
                        print("you have no idea what youre doing and pull the wrong leaver causing the generator to explode, killing you in the process. You loose")

                    else:
                        print("you stay in the cold and dark, during the night a small group of zombies made their way into the builiding with you as you didnt check for open doors or other entry points and they attack you in your sleep, you have now become a zombie. You Lose the game")


    elif answer == "right":

        answer = input("you contiue down the path for a while longer, You come across a dead man, all beaten and with bite marks, you see that he has a gun, Do you take it or leave it? (take/leave)")

        if answer == "take":

            print("Stupid choice that was a zombie and now you have been bitten and now youre dead")

        elif answer == "leave":

            answer = input("You continue down the path and see a large swarm of zombies you can either fight them or try and go through a building to escape them (fight/building")

            if answer == "fight":
                print("Pretty Stupid choice, theyre zombies and youre ... well youre you, and youre dead")


            elif answer == "building":

                answer = input("okay were in the building, theres a zipwire on the roof or you can look for supplies? (zipewire/supplies)")

                if answer == "zipewire":
                    print("you ran into a group of mainiacs and they have captured you and made you a slave, you lose!!")


                elif answer == "supplies":

                    answer = input("nice, you found food, clothes, a gun and keys to a car, are you going yo risk unlocking the car and making noise which could alert the zombies or are you going to find another way? (unlock/other)")

                    if answer == "other":
                        print("Poor choice there is to many of them and now youre dead")

                    elif answer == "unlock":

                        answer = input("okay you got to the car and it has a full tank of fuel, its only a few hour drive to the air feild, do you drive there now in the dark or wait till the morning? (morning/now)")

                        if answer == "morning":
                            print("nope, the zombies are surrounding you and destory the car and you inside it, you lost")


                        elif answer == "now":
                            print("you made it to the air strip and meet up with your friends, youre safe and you win the game!!!!")


else:
     print ("fine dont play :(")
```

Output when I turn right.

```
Welcome to the zombie apocalypse game, Your name is Dion
the apocalypse has been going on for the past year and a half
you have been separated from your group and must make your way to the air field by making the right choices
make the wrong choices and you will loose the game and die.
some choices may seem correct at the time but will lead you down a path of death
Lets Hope You Can Make It!
Would you like to play the game? (yes/no)yes
you are walking down a street, you reach a crossroad, would you like to go left or right? (left/right)right
you contiue down the path for a while longer, You come across a dead man, all beaten and with bite marks, you see that he has a gun, Do you take it or leave it? (take/leave)leave
You continue down the path and see a large swarm of zombies you can either fight them or try and go through a building to escape them (fight/buildingbuilding
okay were in the building, theres a zipwire on the roof or you can look for supplies? (zipewire/supplies)supplies
nice, you found food, clothes, a gun and keys to a car, are you going yo risk unlocking the car and making noise which could alert the zombies or are you going to find another way? (unlock/other)unlock
okay you got to the car and it has a full tank of fuel, its only a few hour drive to the air feild, do you drive there now in the dark or wait till the morning? (morning/now)now
you made it to the air strip and meet up with your friends, youre safe and you win the game!!!!
```

Output when you turn left.

```
Welcome to the zombie apocalypse game, Your name is Dion
the apocalypse has been going on for the past year and a half
you have been separated from your group and must make your way to the air field by making the right choices
make the wrong choices and you will loose the game and die.
some choices may seem correct at the time but will lead you down a path of death
Lets Hope You Can Make It!
Would you like to play the game? (yes/no)yes
you are walking down a street, you reach a crossroad, would you like to go left or right? (left/right)left
you walking into a mugger, Do you fight or run? (fight/run)run
nice choice, you ran away from the mugger, you now come to another split in the road, are you going left or right?? (left/right)right
In the distance you see a fire and some tents, you can either go to the tents and see what happens or try to find your own shelter (tents/yourself)yourself
you find a small bulding that is empty, you decide to make camp here for the night, in the back you notice a generator, do you try and start it or leave it and sleep in the cold and dark? (start/leave)start
you have no idea what youre doing and pull the wrong leaver causing the generator to explode, killing you in the process. You loose
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is just responding to your input, then running through to the end. There's nothing to make it go back to the start, so you are only ever asking for one or two answers.

Is this homework? I'll assume so, and just give you a hint. Try a `while` loop. This is how they look.

```py
exit = False

while not exit:
    answer = input("What do you do?")

    if "exit" in answer.lower():
        exit = True
```

Comment: where would i put that tho??

Comment: Around all your inputs and responses. Try running it by itself, and understanding how it works, and I'm sure you'll work out how to apply it to your code.

Comment: We are only supposed to give hints to homework problems - see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions